# Path For Nav Link Adds On

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

In my rails app I have a bootstrap nav menu with five items, each with a `welcome/_____.html.erb` document to which the menu item is linked (e.g. `welcome/personality`, `welcome/game`, etc.).

I put this as the link to the new page for the first menu item:

```
 <a href="welcome/personality" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Know Your<br>Personality</a>
```

And it works fine, but trying to click on the next menu item using the same `href="welcome/game"` link gives me an error message indicating it is trying to access `welcome/welcome/game`.

This is in my `application.html.erb` file, so it's not something I can change from page to page.  Can anyone see a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `href` to `/welcome/personality`. Notice the `/` in the front which tells your router to use the `root_url` and add what you have, otherwise it will keep adding `/welcome/welcome/welcome...`

Comment: How about instead of using the link manually, you use the rails helper. Something like `game_welcome_path`?

Comment: That's the only way I can get it to work. Good enough for now, but I'm still curious about the why of the original error...